# Probability of trials without replacement using conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> A bag contains $5$ red marbles and $3$ black marbles. Three marbles are drawn one by one without replacement. What is the probability that at least one of the three marbles drawn be black, if the first marble is red?

**Attempt:1**
$$
E:\text{first marble is red}\\
F:\text{at least one of the marbles drawn be black}\\
F':\text{none of the marbles drawn be black}\\
n(S)=8*7*6\\
n(F'\cap E)=n(R_1R_2R_3)=5*4*3\\
n(E)=n(\{(R_1R_2R_3),(R_1B_2R_3),(R_1R_2B_3),(R_1B_2B_3)\})\\=5*4*3+5*3*4+5*4*3+5*3*2=60+60+60+30=210\\
\begin{align}
&P(\text{at least 1 of the 3 marbles black|1$^\text{st}$ marble red})
=P(F|E)\\&=1-P(F'|E)=1-\frac{60}{210}=1-\frac{2}{7}=\color{red}{\frac{5}{7}}
\end{align}
$$
**Attempt:2**
$$
\begin{align}
&P(\text{at least 1 of the 3 marbles black|1$^\text{st}$ marble red})
=P(F|E)\\&=1-P(F'|E)=1-P(R_1R_2R_3)\\&=1-P(R_1)P(R_2|R_1)P(R_3|R_1R_2)=1-\frac{5}{8}.\frac{\frac{5*4}{8*7}}{\frac{5}{8}}.\frac{\frac{5*4*3}{8*7*6}}{\frac{5*4}{8*7}}=1-\frac{5}{28}\\&=\color{blue}{\frac{23}{28}}
\end{align}
$$
**OR**
$$
\begin{align}
&P(\text{at least 1 of the 3 marbles black|1$^\text{st}$ marble red})=P(F|E)\\&=1-P(F'|E)=1-P(R_1R_2R_3)=1-\frac{5*4*3}{8*7*6}=1-\frac{5}{28}=\color{blue}{\frac{23}{28}}
\end{align}
$$
**Attempt:3**
$$
\begin{align}
&P(\text{at least 1 of the 3 marbles black|1$^\text{st}$ marble red})=P(F|E)\\&=P(R_1B_2R_3)+P(R_1R_2B_3)+P(R_1B_2B_3)\\&=\frac{5*3*4}{8*7*6}+\frac{5*4*3}{8*7*6}+\frac{5*3*2}{8*7*6}=\frac{10+10+5}{4*7*2}=\color{green}{\frac{25}{56}}
\end{align}
$$
The solution of the above problem is stated to be $\frac{25}{56}$ as in my Attempt 3, but why am I not getting the right solution in Attempt $1$ and Attempt $2$ ?

Comment: My solution is $\Large{\frac{5}{7}}$. You´ve forgotten to use  $P(A)$ at method 2.

Comment: More specific: $P(\color{red}RB\color{red}R)+P(\color{red}R\color{red}RB)+P(\color{red}RBB)$ is $P(A\cap B)$ rather than $P(B|A)$

Comment: @callculus $\frac{25}{56}$ is the solution right ?. How $\frac{5}{7}$ ?

Comment: No, it is 5/7 as I said. $P(B|A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}=\frac{25/56}{\frac58}=\frac57$ Your $P(B|A)$ should be $P(A \cap B)$

Comment: @callculus pls check https://www.studyrankersonline.com/30819/bag-contains-5-red-marbles-and-3-black-marbles, https://www.meritnation.com/ask-answer/question/a-bag-contains-5-red-marbles-and-3-black-marbles-three-marbl/probability/9025351

Comment: I´ve checked it. The solutions are the solution for $P(A \cap B)$, but you want $P(B|A)$ For this purpose you apply [$\texttt{Bayes’ theorem}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem). $P(B|A)=\frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)}$ To say it clear: The given solutions at the links are wrong.

Comment: @callculus i'm srry but i'm still confused. So what the statement of the problem really seeking to find ? gooling shows both the results $\frac{5}{7}$ and $\frac{25}{56}$

Comment: Don´t google, just ask MSE! I have posted an answer. I hope it is comprehensible. You are free to ask if something is still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the elementary events for the answer. Firstly I use your definition of events:

$E:\text{first marble is red}\\
F:\text{at least one of the marbles drawn be black}\\$

You have to find the probability that you draw at least 3 black marbles given the first marble is red. This is $P(F|E)$

In total we have these 8 cases:

$$rrr, rrb, rbr, brr, bbr, brb, rbb, bbb$$

Now we list the cases where  at least 1 black marble is drawn **and** the first marble is red.

$$rrb, rbr, rbb$$

The probability is $$P(F\cap E)=\frac{5}{8}\cdot \frac{4}{7}\cdot \frac{3}{6}+\frac{5}{8}\cdot \frac{3}{7}\cdot \frac{4}{6}+\frac{5}{8}\cdot \frac{3}{7}\cdot \frac{2}{7}=\frac{25}{56}$$

Now we calculate P(A). The events are $rrr, rrb, rbr,  rbb$ Therefore

$$P(E)=\frac{5}{8}\cdot \frac{4}{7}\cdot \frac{3}{6}+\frac{5}{8}\cdot \frac{4}{7}\cdot \frac{3}{6}+\frac{5}{8}\cdot \frac{3}{7}\cdot \frac{4}{6}+\frac{5}{8}\cdot \frac{3}{7}\cdot \frac{2}{6}=\frac{5}{8}$$

Now we apply the  [Bayes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem)

$$P(F|E)=\frac{P(F\cap E)}{P(E)}=\frac{\frac{25}{56}}{\frac{5}{8}}=\frac{25}{56}\cdot \frac{8}{5}=\frac{5}{56}\cdot \frac{8}{1}=\frac{5}{7}\cdot \frac{1}{1}=\boxed{\frac57}$$

---

> $$ \begin{align} &P(\text{at least 1 of the 3 marbles
>  black|1$^\text{st}$ marble
>  red})=P(F|E)\\&=1-P(F'|E)=1-P(R_1R_2R_3)=1-\frac{5*4*3}{8*7*6}=1-\frac{5}{28}=\color{blue}{\frac{23}{28}}
>  \end{align} $$

Here you miss the Bayes theorem as well.

$$P(F'|E)=\frac{P(F'\cap E)}{P(E)}$$

$P(F'\cap E)=\frac{5\cdot 4\cdot 3}{8\cdot 7\cdot 6}$

And $P(E)=\frac58$ Thus

$$P(F|E)=1-P(F'|E)=1-\frac{P(F'\cap E)}{P(E)}=1-\frac{\frac{5\cdot 4\cdot 3}{8\cdot 7\cdot 6}}{\frac58}=1-\frac27=\boxed{\frac57}$$

Many ways lead to Rome.

Comment: ok. so i think, i wrongly considered $R_1R_2R_3$ to be same as $F'|E$.Former is the event that all three trials select "red", later is the event that we already know the first trial gives "red" considering that how probable is the event that second and third trials give "red", which is what the actual problem seeking for, right ?.

Comment: @ss1729 What you have written is totally correct.